# Parse pipe-separated file with variable column count and substitute missing columns to convert to fixed column count

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a pipe-separated (`|`) file where each line can have a variable number of columns/fields. Only the first two fields and the last two fields are always present, in between there can be a varying (but even) number of fields up to 10, so that the line overall has up to 14 fields (2 + 0 ... 10 + 2).

The goal is to substitute "missing" fields and convert the file to one with a fixed number of columns per line.

The "variable" fields are characterized by always consisting of one "index key" of the form `C_A` ... `C_E` and one value.

Example input:

```
10|100|C_A|val_18|C_D|val_20|50|60
40|200|C_A|val_5|C_B|val_10|C_C|val_30|C_D|val_90|C_E|val_83|40|45
80|100|C_E|val_90|50|60
```

This is the expected output:

```
10|100|C_A|val_18|||||C_D|val_20|||50|60
40|200|C_A|val_5|C_B|val_10|C_C|val_30|C_D|val_90|C_E|val_83|40|45
80|100|||||||||C_E|val_90|50|60
```

Answer (score 0):

Using  `GNU awk` we can approach the problem by means of mapping names with field indices.

- C_A => $3
- C_B => $5
  ... and so on

```
$ awk '
  BEGIN {
    OFS = FS = "|"
    n = split("A-B-C-D-E", x, "-")
    for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) h["C_" x[i]] = 2*(i-1) + 3
  }
  {
    # record which out of
    # ca/cb/.../ce present
    for (i=3; i<NF-2; i+=2) seen[$i] = $(i+1)

    # store fields in preparation
    # for re-filling them based on seen
    nf = split($0, f, FS); $0=""

    # fill up the first two..easy does it
    $(1) = f[1]
    $(2) = f[2]

    # recall which fields c_? 
    # were seen then fill up
    # corresponding field and field value 
    for (var in h) {
      i = h[var]
      if (var in seen) {
        $(i) = var
        $(i+1) = seen[var]
      } else { $(i) = $(i+1) = ""}
    }

    # append the last two fields
    $(NF+1) = f[nf-1]
    $(NF+1) = f[nf]
    # above line **NOT** a typo

    # clear out the array seen
    # for the next iteration
    split("", seen, ".")
  }1
' file
```

**Results:**

```
10|100|C_A|val_18|||||C_D|val_20|||50|60
40|200|C_A|val_5|C_B|val_10|C_C|val_30|C_D|val_90|C_E|val_83|40|45
80|100|||||||||C_E|val_90|50|60
```

Comment: works for my case. TQ

Answer (score 0):

Read the variable fields into arrays, print the arrays, yielding empty strings when not used in a line (don't forget `-F '|'`):

```
BEGIN{
    # initialize expected keys for file (value 1 not used)
    all_keys["C_A"]=1;
    all_keys["C_B"]=1;
    all_keys["C_C"]=1;
    all_keys["C_D"]=1;
    all_keys["C_E"]=1;
 }
 {
    # fill arrays for line
    for(i=3;i<NF-1;i+=2) {
        key[$i]=$i;
        value[$i]=$i+1;
    }
    # first two fields
    printf $1"|"$2"|";
    # all variable key/value pairs, occurring on line or not
    for (k in all_keys) {
        printf key[k]"|"value[k]"|";
    }
    # last two fields
    print $NF-1"|"$NF;
    # delete arrays so we don't carry over values into the next line
    delete key;
    delete value;
}
```

Comment: code is short n works for my case. TQ